# Can I use my own voice or someone's voice with permission?

Tags: actions-on-google

For google home actions, can I use my own voice or someone else's voice with permission? Can I read the text responses, record them, and play them back as audio files?

Earplay is an example on Alexa:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01K8V6NSI?ie=UTF8&path=%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB01K8V6NSI&ref_=skillrw_dsk_si_dp&useRedirectOnSuccess=1&](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K8V6NSI)

A guy from Gupshup said that it is not allowed:
https://youtu.be/f-mPuEbJ-nU?t=45m13s
I didn't see where it was not allowed in the terms of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Progressive does this with their Google Action.

Answer (score 1):

"the platform does not allow that" does not mean that it is legally not allowed, but that it is simply not possible.

Both Alexa and Google Assistant have a default voice which can not be changed.

Comment: They can be changed.

Comment: I don't know about Alexa, but Google's Home voice can be changed.

Comment: You can choose between 4 voices on Google Home, right? But you can not download a 3rd party voice, if I'm not mistaking (?)

Comment: Yes, on Google home you can choose between voices. But I am not talking about that.
Sorry, I was not clear. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

When developing an Action, you can select from one of four voices (two male, two female) to use. You can't use the default Google Assistant voice. There is no technical way to use another voice.

While you *can* send audio files, and these audio files can contain a voice, this would be a lot of work for little benefit.

Comment: Thanks, but I know it can be done technically. I am asking about policy.

Comment: After I created this question, I went to a Google Home meetup and they said there is an action that creating their own audio files for their responses.

Comment: The bot is actually on Alexa. It is called Earplay.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01K8V6NSI?ie=UTF8&path=%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB01K8V6NSI&ref_=skillrw_dsk_si_dp&useRedirectOnSuccess=1&

Comment: I went to the SuperBot Conference and a person from Google pointed out Progressive has done this their Google Action.